# Why does the store() method work but not update()?

Tags: php, laravel

My code works during `store()`, but once I try to update the stored image it does nothing. When I checked using `dd()` there is no file uploaded at all.

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required',
        'district' => 'required',
        'comment' => 'required',
        'full_comment' => 'required',
        'photo' => 'sometimes|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $game = Game::find($id);
    $game->title = $request->get('title');
    $game->type = $request->get('type');
    $game->city = $request->get('city');
    $game->district = $request->get('district');
    $game->comment = $request->get('comment');
    $game->full_comment = $request->get('full_comment');

    if ($request->has('photo')) {
        $game->photo = $request->get('photo');
        $photoName = $game->id.'photo'.time().'.'.request()->photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $game->photo = $photoName;
        $request->photo->storeAs('game-photos', $photoName);
    }
    $game->save();

    return redirect('/games')->with('success', 'Game has been  updated');
}
```

Comment: Please try to be more clear in your problem, such as by presenting the whole `store` and `update` methods. Right now, for example, you have a `$game` variable that comes from nowhere.

Comment: @FrancinaldoAlmeida sorry, I updated code

Comment: Try to use `hasFile('photo')` instead of `has('photo')`, and check if this condition is true so we can further debug the code.

Comment: @FrancinaldoAlmeida I tried but photo still not uploading, I even tried to remove if statement, then I get error 'Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null'. Game update is working with if statement but photo is not updating

Comment: Can you check your forms has the proper `enctype="multipart/form-data"` set?

Comment: @FrancinaldoAlmeida yes it's correct

Answer (score 0):

The provided controller method, while not optimal, should work correctly (and does in my case). Please compare your form to the following snippet:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('game.update', $game) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    {!! method_field('PUT') !!}
    <input type="file" name="photo">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Also, paste this at the very top of your `update` method. It will show any files that are submitted, or an empty array if none are.

```
dd($request->files);
```